# Javascript post tweet with image url

Tags: javascript, twitter

Is there any way to post a tweet with an image url and show that image in the tweet?

In the API Documentation is only specified that you can upload image to twitter and then use the response id to post a tweet using that image.

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/media/upload